# Android: How to get product info after barcode scanning?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

Alright, so I'm trying to write a program for Android for a project for school, I figured out how to use Intents to scan, but once I find a product, how do I get that info into my app? For example, say I'm getting info from upcdatabase.com, I would just add the barcode number to the end of the url, but then how to I draw that data in? The same with Google search, how would I draw the data and the image of the item into the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPCDatabase doesn't seem to provide a API or other queries to do a lookup. So if you have to use UPCDatabase i would try to use a [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) and make a GET to retrieve the data from the URL your build with your barcode. Then you have to somehow parse the result so that you will get the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

No. upcdatabase.com provides webservice to access data, which is providig xml-rpc webservice to fetch and add items to their database,  for more information, you can look into below link,

http://www.upcdatabase.com/xmlrpc.asp